# HD P2SH Wallets Compatibility with P2WPKH

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, p2sh, p2wpkh

Are BIP32 Hierarchal Deterministic compatible  with P2SH addresses? Not as multisig but instead for the new P2WPKH?